Factor a polynomial expression
I want to factorize the following polynomial in MATHEMATICA:
2.49 + 1.42 x - 0.30 x^2 + 1.47 y - 3.16 x y - 
 7.80 y^2

as a factor of two polynomial of one degree even approximatively, but Factor[ ] doesn't work on the way I desired
Or at least is there a way in MATHEMATICA to simplify the polynomial as much as possible

Use rational coefficients first, i.e 249/100 for 2.49.   Equate poly to a variable like myPoly Then use IrreduciblePolynomialQ[myPoly] which returns True.  Also, good idea in this forum to show some effort solving problem; post the code you tried.

Define, precisely, "even approximately."

@DavidG.Stork I mean even if we could writing it as (a+bx+cy)(d+ex+fy)  with approximate values for a, b, c, d, e and f

If I look at the output from (a+b*x+c*y)(d+e*x+f*y)//Expand and I match up coefficients with your original polynomial then I think I get Reduce[{a*d==249/100,b*d+a*e==142/100,b*e==-30/100, c*d+a*f==147/100,c*e+b*f==-316/100,c*f==-780/100}, {a,b,c,d,e,f}] and that returns False claiming it cannot find values for a,b,c,d,e,f that satisfy your problem. Maybe you could come up with a different polynomial to match. Please check that very carefully before you even think of trusting that.

Define, precisely, "with approximate values for a, b, c, d, e and f."
